# How to refresh particular page in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a dashboard page which needs to refresh after every 15 minutes. So how can I do this.

Here is my dashboard action from my controller

```
def dashboard
  @widgets = Widget.all
end
```

I have already added "Refresh" button on the page.

**dashboard.html.haml**

```
  = link_to "Refresh Page", "#", :id => "refresh-page"
```

**dashboard.js**

```
$("#refresh-page").click(function(){
        location.reload();
});
```

I also tried with

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300" />
```

and it is working fine page is refreshing after 5 minutes but it is applying to the all pages and this is causing problem.

So how can I refresh only particular page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
- if controller.controller_name == your_controller_name && controller.action_name == your_action_name
  %meta{:content => "100", "http-equiv" => "refresh"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, in your javascript add this

```
setInterval("$('#refresh-page').trigger('click')",900000);
```